# How do I draw and set an angle to the axis of a rotating 3D Object?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a rotating planet (Saturn with rings) and I have set the camera like so:

```
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.05, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 3;
  camera.position.y = 1;
  camera.position.x = 1;
```

What I got here is a planet being seen at a certain angle, but the planet itself is on a flat x-y-z axis.

This is how it looks: [Saturn & Rings](http://codepen.io/marvindanig/pen/GJqepZ)

I wish to draw a dashed/dotted line to show the actual axis of the planet which is at an angle 'Ɵ' to the orthogonal of the solar plane (assuming solar-plane = 'x-z'). And how to alter the angle at which default axes (XYZ) of the planet are set to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate your planet mesh on an axis, you can use a pattern like this one:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

mesh.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 10 ) ); // show the local coordinate system

mesh.rotation.set( 0, 0, - Math.PI / 8 ); // set initial orientation
```

Then, in your render loop,

```
mesh.rotateY( 0.01 ); // rotate mesh around its local Y-axis
```

three.js r.71